# PHP/MySQL - How to display PHP generated text any where on a web page using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display part of the script any where on the web page that generates the text to tell the user they submitted something.

How can I fix my script in-order to do this? And what part of my code should be changed?

Here is the part of the script that I want to display anywhere on a web page.

```
if (count($tags) == 1){
        echo $tags[0] . " has been entered";
} else {
        echo implode(", ", $tags) . " have been entered";           
}
```

Here is the full script.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
    $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT questions_tags.*, tags.* FROM questions_tags, tags");
    if (!$dbc) {
        print mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }

    $page = '3';

    $tag = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['tag']);

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
    $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT questions_tags.*, tags.* FROM questions_tags INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = questions_tags.tag_id WHERE questions_tags.users_questions_id='$page'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($dbc) >= 0){

        if (isset($_POST['tag'])) {
                $tags = explode(",", $_POST['tag']);

                for ($x = 0; $x < count($tags); $x++){
                        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
                        $clean_url = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $page);

                        $query1 = "INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES ('" . $tags[$x] . "')";

                        if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $query1)) {
                                print mysqli_error($mysqli);
                                return;
                        }

                        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
                        $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag='" . $tags[$x] . "'");


                        if (!$dbc) {
                                print mysqli_error($mysqli);
                        }  else {
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){
                                        $id = $row["id"];
                                }
                        }
                        $query2 = "INSERT INTO questions_tags (tag_id, users_questions_id) VALUES ('$id', '$page')";

                        if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $query2)) {
                                print mysqli_error($mysqli);
                                return;
                        }
                }

                        if (count($tags) == 1){
                                echo $tags[0] . " has been entered";
                        } else {
                                echo implode(", ", $tags) . " have been entered";

                        }
        }

        if (!$dbc) {
                print mysqli_error($mysqli);
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is your POST tag variable set?
Is that query returning rows?

Comment: It's returning what the user entered in so I believe so ex. `<input type="text" name="tag" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['tag'])) echo $_POST['tag']; ?>" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the page is PHP you can have any number of opening and closing tags:

```
<?php
$count = count($tags);
if ($count == 0) {
   $str = 'No tags have been entered.';
else if ($count == 1) {
    $str = htmlentities($tags[0]) . " has been entered";
} else {
    $str = htmlentities(implode(", ", $tags)) . " have been entered";                       
}
?>

<p>HTML code here</p>
<?php echo $str; ?>
<p>More HTML</p>
```

Please note that for security purposes (to prevent cross-site scripting) you should take measures to filter any page output that was generated by the user.  Take a quick glance over at [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: So would I just replace that portion of my code with something like this?

Comment: @slapthis - Yes, this would be safer.